# AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute '_le'

Tags: python, xgboost, predict

I am trying to fit my xgboost model object (0.60 version) on OOT data, but keep getting error. I am using below line of code:

```
fname = "xgb"  
if isinstance(xgb, XGBClassifier):
 regressor = XGBClassifier()
 r = pickle.load(open(fname, "rb" ))
 print(r)
 regressor._Booster = r._Booster
 regressor.set_params(**r.get_xgb_params())

y_predict = regressor.predict(oot)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute '_le'
```

I also tried scoring the OOT data using alternate way:

```
scored = scored_data.predict(oot)
```

Then i get below error (i have created similar environment replicating model dev)

```
class_probs = self.booster().predict(test_dmatrix,output_margin=output_margin,ntree_limit=ntree_limit)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You're pickling not the whole object I think, that's the issue. What is the code for pickling?

Comment: scored_data = pd.read_pickle("xgb.pkl")

Comment: did you solve this? I'm getting this error when using the official documentation way of save_model() and load_model()

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue with version 0.90. Upgrading to 1.6.1 fixed it for me.